# Pandas dataframe with name attribute

Tags: python, pandas

I am in the middle of an eda process using the pandas profiling and for a specific dataframe I have the error

> 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

From what I could discover this attribute should not exist. I can visualize it when doing df.columns and in other dataframes it does not appear. I also can not change it with df.name = 'name here'. Is there any way to remove it?

I am creating a script with Jupyter Lab installed by Anaconda.

My code:

```
import pandas_profiling as pp

df_planilhas.columns
Index(['VIAGEM', 'OT', 'DATA', 'HORA', 'CARGA', 'NF', 'TIPONF', 'CIA',
       'ORIGEM', 'CIA', 'DESTINO', 'TRANSP', 'PLACA', 'FRETE', 'ITENS',
       'CUBAGEMREAL', 'PESOREAL', 'VALOR', 'TIPO', 'COD', 'FLAG',
       'OBSERVAÇÃO'],
      dtype='object', **name=0**)

profile = pp.ProfileReport(df_planilhas)
```

---

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 profile = pp.ProfileReport(df_planilhas)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling__init__.py
>   in **init**(self, df, **kwargs)
>        64         sample = kwargs.get('sample', df.head())
>        65 
>   ---> 66         description_set = describe(df, **kwargs)
>        67 
>        68         self.html = to_html(sample,
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\describe.py
>   in describe(df, bins, check_correlation, correlation_threshold,
>   correlation_overrides, check_recoded, pool_size, **kwargs)
>       413         'table': table_stats,
>       414         'variables': variable_stats.T,
>   --> 415         'freq': {k: (base.get_groupby_statistic(df[k])[0] if variable_stats[k].type != base.S_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED else None) for k in
>   df.columns},
>       416         'correlations': {'pearson': dfcorrPear, 'spearman': dfcorrSpear}
>       417     }
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\describe.py
>   in (.0)
>       413         'table': table_stats,
>       414         'variables': variable_stats.T,
>   --> 415         'freq': {k: (base.get_groupby_statistic(df[k])[0] if variable_stats[k].type != base.S_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED else None) for k in
>   df.columns},
>       416         'correlations': {'pearson': dfcorrPear, 'spearman': dfcorrSpear}
>       417     }
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\base.py
>   in get_groupby_statistic(data)
>        42         value count and distinct count
>        43     """
>   ---> 44     if data.name is not None and data.name in _VALUE_COUNTS_MEMO:
>        45         return _VALUE_COUNTS_MEMO[data.name]
>        46
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
>   in **getattr**(self, name)    4374             if
>   self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):    4375
>   return self[name]
>   -> 4376             return object.**getattribute**(self, name)    4377     4378     def **setattr**(self, name, value):
>
> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: I have discovered that the name attribute is created when I name the headers with df_planilhas.columns = df_planilhas.iloc [0]. I tried to use the tolist (df_planilhas.columns = df_planilhas.iloc [0] .tolist ()) and when I call a df.columns the name = 0 no longer appears, however the same error occurs when using profiling ('DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name')

Answer (score 0):

With help, I discovered that the problem was two headers with the same name. After the modification the pandas profiling could be generated.